# Automatically move a sprite to catch another sprite

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to make a ping pong like game using box2d. Like said game, there's a ball and 2 paddles. One of the paddles is moved by the player using accelerometer. I have this working fine. On the other hand, I want the 2nd paddle to act like some kind of wall that would catch the ball and hit it back to the player.

My problem is the ball is bouncing with the use of gravity and force so I'm not sure how I can tell the 2nd paddle to move where the ball is headed to catch it. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime) dt {
if(_isPaused == FALSE)
{
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            if(sprite.tag == 3)
            {
                [self schedule:@selector(moveObj:)interval:0.0];
                b2Vec2 autoPos = b2Vec2(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
                float32 autoAngle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(sprite.rotation);

                b->SetTransform(autoPos, autoAngle);
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos)
    {
        MyContact contact = *pos;

        if((contact.fixtureA == _tPaddleFixture && contact.fixtureB == _ballFixture) || (contact.fixtureA == _ballFixture && contact.fixtureB == _tPaddleFixture))
        {
            _isHit = TRUE;
        }
    }
}}

-(void)moveObj:(ccTime)dt{
if(_isHit == TRUE)
{
    //I need the code here
    NSLog(@"HIT");
}
else
{
    tPaddle.position = ccp(160, tPaddle.position.y);
}}
```

Currently, I'm just printing a message that says hit if the paddle and the ball should collide (only at the center) but I'm not sure how to tell tPaddle to move wherever the ball is headed to, to catch it. Can somebody please give me an idea how I can implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant you just try to keep the paddle's `x` coordinate and ball's `x` coordinate equal? For example if the ball goes left so will the paddle. Or do I completely not understand the question? I imagine your game to look like this

```
******************
*  ***           *
*                *
*      *         *
*                *
*           ***  *
******************
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it looks at the moment. I actually haven't thought of making the x-coordinates equal. Wouldn't that mean that if the ball is bouncing left to right and vice versa, the paddle would be moving left to right while waiting for the ball to actually hit it?

Comment: Yes it would, but it's simple to implement =) And maybe it wouldnt look awful as well.

Comment: Wow, I've been so stuck with the collision for quite a long time I didn't think of doing something simple as that. Thanks so much! :)